# How to remove the elements of an array which are equal in value?

Tags: java, arrays

Using ArrayUtills in java code it is possible to remove an element from an java array.
Below is the code which removes an element at a particlular index (in the code it is '2', which removes element value equalto '10'.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;


public class RemoveObjectFromArray{

 public static void main(String args[]) {


     int[] test = new int[] { 10, 13, 10, 10, 105};

     System.out.println("Original Array : size : " + test.length );
     System.out.println("Contents : " + Arrays.toString(test));

     //let's remove or delete an element from Array using Apache Commons ArrayUtils
     test = ArrayUtils.remove(test, 2); //removing element at index 2

     //Size of array must be 1 less than original array after deleting an element
     System.out.println("Size of array after removing an element  : " + test.length);
     System.out.println("Content of Array after removing an object : "
                       + Arrays.toString(test));

 } }
```

It gives the output as:

```
run:
Original Array : size : 5
Contents : [10, 13, 10, 10, 105]
Size of array after removing an element  : 4
Content of Array after removing an object : [10, 13, 10, 105]
```

How the code can be amended to get the following output:

```
run:
Original Array : size : 5
Contents : [10, 13, 10, 10, 105]
Size of array after removing an element  : 2
Content of Array after removing an object : [ 13, 105]
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use a Set (and then convert it back to an array)?

Comment: To use set will be my last option if ArrayUtils or something like it fails.

Comment: You can use the function multiple times.

Comment: Are you sure you want to remove all elements which are duplicated.  Usually you would leave one e.g. `[10, 13, 105]`

Comment: @user3678356 - using a set might be your last, unfortunately it is also your simplest option :)

Comment: The array shown in the code is dummy. I have to deal with array having many thousands elements multiple use of function is impractical. I am looking something like. If( [i]==10) {ArrayUtils.remove([i])};

Comment: @user3678356: not only is it the simplest solution, but the fastest as well since a `TreeSet<T>` or `HashSet<T>` will result in fast membership checking and adding/removing elements is only **log(n)** time (**n** for an array).

Comment: @CommuSoft converting an array to a Set is already O(n), isn't it?

Comment: @Kent: well removing an item from an array where the order is important is another O(n) factor. At most you need to remove O(n) such values, thus the problem is O(n^2) with an array while using a `TreeSet<T>` with a reasonable ordering will result in O(n log n) and a `HashSet<T>` with a reasonable hash function in O(n)

Comment: @CommuSoft what I meant is, no matter what lib/data structure was used for this problem, the solution won't be faster than O(n) . what "simpler" is just the lines of codes. in fact the `new Set()` and `ArrayUtils` internal iterates/loop the array through. If we have to do the loop, why not just finish the work during the loop and avoid to add extra overhead? `c * n + k` is  `O(n)` too, but it will slower than `n`.  the `k` is for the hashfunc. Note that we could think hashfunc has `O(1)`, not `O(n)`

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to implement your own list where the add() method checks to see if the value is already in the list? Granted, depending on what you want to store in there you might have to override hashCode() and equals(), but you could use it then for anything.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code

```
while (ArrayUtils.contains(test, 10))  {
  //let's remove or delete an element from Array using Apache Commons ArrayUtils
  test = ArrayUtils.removeElement(test, 10); //removing element with value 10
}
```

It should solve your problem.

Comment: This will only solve this particular case, I assume OP wants this to work on any array.

Comment: Not an efficient solution. The OP will have to Iterate through the entire array. Removing and moving the elements in the array take some time as well.

Answer (score 2):

I would use an ArrayList in your case but if you want to stick with your array you can do the following:

```
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
  if (test[i] == 10) {
    count++;
  }
 }
 int[] newTest = new int[count];
 count = 0;
 for( int = 0; i < test.length; i++){
   if(test[i] != 10){
     newTest[count++] = test[i];
   }
  }
```

i didn't test it

Answer (score 2):

Albeit not an elegant way but if you want to only use arrays you can use something along the lines of:

```
public static void removeDupes(int[] array) {

    int[] forbiddenNumbers = new int[array.length];

    Arrays.sort(array);

    for(int number : array) {
        if(ArrayUtils.contains(forbiddenNumbers, number){
            int index = Arrays.binarySearch(array, number);
            while(index >= 0) {
                ArrayUtils.remove(array, index);
                index = Arrays.binarySearch(array, number);
            }
            ArrayUtils.remove(forbiddenNumbers, Arrays.binarySearch(forbiddenNumbers, number);
        } else {
            ArrayUtils.add(forbiddenNumbers, number);
        }
    }
}
```

This should work on any dupes present in the array.

What this does is basically goes through the array, saving all unique numbers in another array, and once a duplicate is encountered in the array, it removes all instances of that number in the original array, afterwards it removes the number from the unique number array since it is no longer present in the original array.

This is a really backbreaking solution, and you should seriously consider using other means (e.g. using sets) but if you want to do it in pure arrays then this should work.

Answer (score 2):

this do the job in only one loop without adding overheads from other libraries or data structures, complexity `O(n)`

```
        int[] test = new int[] { 10, 13, 10, 10, 105};
        int tobeDel = 10;
        int[] tmp = new int[test.length];
        int j=0;
        for (int i=0;i<test.length;i++) {
            if (test[i] == tobeDel) {
                continue;
            }    
            tmp[j] = test[i];
            j++;
        }
        int[] result = new int[j];
        System.arraycopy(tmp, 0, result, 0, j);
```

if you write your own method, return the `result`.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

I never found any single function for your requirement, but this code will do.

```
while(ArrayUtils.removeElement(test,10).length!=test.length)
    test=ArrayUtils.removeElement(test,10);
```

You can use [**removeElement**](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#removeElement%28boolean%5B%5D,%20boolean%29) which will remove the element and return the new array. If  there is nothing to delete then it will return the same list.

---

**Solution 2**

This will also do the same But without any iteration. If thats what you are looking for.

```
Arrays.sort(test);
int[] finalValue =ArrayUtils.subarray(test, 0, ArrayUtils.indexOf(test,10));
ArrayUtils.addAll(finalValue,ArrayUtils.subarray(test,ArrayUtils.lastIndexOf(test,10), test.length));
```

This will sort the arrays and cut the arrays from the begining to the first occurence, and then from the last occurence to the end of array.!!

Comment: worst case `O(n^2)` ? (solution 1)

Comment: @Kent Yes but it can be simplified, i just given him the logic. It must be modified to make it better. !! After-all i am not doing his homework. ;-)

Comment: IMO, n*n could be the slowest solution for this problem. also the solution 2, it changes a O(n) into O(nlogn), it is not necessary either. And it changes the order of the rest elements. well maybe performance isn't an issue for OP... my 2cents